# JUnit + Powermock - new Date() - NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I am trying to mock a service method where new Date is pass as an argument. But I am geting NullPointer. Getting student object as null. Any help please...

My Service code: (which I can't change as it is already in production and need a lot of approvals)

```
Student student = studentService.getStudent(studentId, new Date());
// Getting NullPointerException. When I debug I see student is null
presentDate = DateUtil.convertSqlTimetoCurrentDate(student.getStartTime());
```

My test class

```
when(studentService.getStudent(1, new Date())).thenReturn(student);
```

I also tried

```
when(studentService.getStudent(1, any(Date.class))).thenReturn(student);
```

and

```
when(studentService.getStudent(eq(1), any(Date.class))).thenReturn(student);
```

and

```
when(studentService.getStudent(1, anyobject())).thenReturn(student);
```

Comment: How do you init mocks in unit test? Probably you forgot @Mock annotation.

Comment: I did use @Mock for StudentService. I am able to mock other methods, only when there is a new Date() is used, n those cases, I am getting return value as null

Comment: Does `studentService.getStudent(anyInt(), any(Date.class))` also fail? I'm guessing a lot of those don't work because you can't use matchers in some arguments but not all of them.

Comment: Do you use real object for student of mock as well?

Comment: Do you get null object or null pointer exception? Can you send stacktrace,

Comment: @user1474111 updated my question. Please see the comment in first 2 lines of code

Answer (score 2):

You need to prepare your class for test and mock Date() constructor so your studentService will be always invoked with the same arguments.

Here is a working example:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( {MockingStudentTest.StudentService.class} )
public class MockingStudentTest {
    private static final Date DATE_TIME = new Date(1398755086992L);

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnTheStudentWithTheRIghtStartTime() throws Exception {
        whenNew(Date.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(DATE_TIME);

        Date startTime = new StudentService().getStudent(10, new Date()).getStartTime();
        System.out.println(startTime);
        assertEquals(DATE_TIME, startTime);
    }

    class Student {
        private final int id;

        private final Date startTime;

        public Student(int id, Date startTime) {
            this.id = id;
            this.startTime = startTime;
        }
        public Date getStartTime() {
            return startTime;
        }
    }

    class StudentService {
        public Student getStudent(int id, Date startTime) {
            return new Student(id, startTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is definitely a great feature of powermock. Thanks for the answer (+1).

Comment: I'm not the author of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Julian provided [a clean solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53953078/2065796) to your problem, but if you want to continue with `any()` the following code should work, please copy-paste and try on your machine.

```
@Test
public void shouldGetStudent() {
    StudentService service = mock(StudentService.class);
    when(service.getStudent(eq(1), any(Date.class))).thenReturn(new Student());

    Student student = service.getStudent(1, new Date());

    assertNotNull(student);
}
```

If it doesn't work for you there might be an issue with the supporting functionality, please check the following options.

1. Make sure the Date used during mocking comes form the correct package (java.utils vs java.sql). Unfortunately if you use the wrong one compiler won't catch it in the `any(Date.class)` call.
2. Make sure `any()` and `eq()` come form `org.mockito.Matchers`.
3. Make sure you instantiate mockito classes correctly.
4. Are you sure the student object from `thenReturn(student)` is not null?